# Find all positive integer $n$ with the property that there is a partition of the set $({n, n + 1, n + 2, n + 3, n + 4, n + 5})$

Tags: combinatorics

find all positive integers $n$ with the property: there is a partition of the set $({n,n+1,n+2,n+3,n+4,n+5})$ into two disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ such that the product of element in $A$ is equal to the one in $B$

How do I approach the  problem quoted above? I tried using parity arguments but  I found nothing. Any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one partition, $A$ say, has more than three elements, them its product is $>n^4$, whereas the product over $B$ is $<(n+5)^2$. This leads to $(1+\frac 5n)^2>n^2$ and so needs only be checked for $n<3$. Beyond that, we need only check partitions into three and three.
Thus we want to find integer solutions of 
$$\tag1 n(n+a_1)(n+a_2)=(n+a_3)(n+a_4)(n+a_5)$$
where $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5\}=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.
Clearly, $(1)$ simplifies to a quadratic equation in $n$ with integer coefficients and constant term $a_3a_4a_5$. Therefore any integer solution of $(1)$ must be a divisor of $a_3a_4a_5$. If $5\in\{a_1,a_2\}$ then automatically $a_3a_4a_5$ is a divisor of $4!=24$.
And if $5\in\{a_3,a_4,a_5\}$, wlog $a_1<a_2$ and $a_3<a_4<a_5=5$, then from $0<a_3$ and $a_2<a_5$ we conclude $a_1>a_4$ as otherwise again the left hand side is smaller than the right hand side; then $a_5>a_2>a_1>a_4$ gives us $a_4\le 2$ so that $a_3a_4a_5$ is a divisor of $10$.
In summary, we need only manually check $n<3$, $n\mid 24$, and $n\mid 10$, i.e.,
$$n=1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,12,24. $$
But we need not really test much: If any of the numbers $n,\ldots, n+5$ is a prime $p>6$, then only one of these numbers is a multiple of $p$ and hence only one side of $(1)$ is divisible by $p$, i.e., for such $n$, no solution exists. This rules out $n=2,3,4,5,6$ (with $p=7$), $n=8,10,12$ (with $p=13$), and $n=24$ (with $p=29$). But the same applies to $n=1$ with $p=5$ because even though $p<6$, it is still the case that $p$ occurs only as a single factor.

---

The same argument with a different twist:
For such a partition where wlog $n\in A$, we'd have some $k$ with $0\le k\le 4$ and some permutation $(a_1,\ldots, a_5)$ of $(1,2,3,4,5)$ that 
$$ \tag2(n+a_{k+1})\cdots (n+a_5)-n(n+a_1)\cdots (n+a_k)=0.$$
If $p$ is prime such that exactly one of the numbers $n,\ldots, n+5$ is a multiple of $p$, $(2)$ cannot hold as we take the differenec  between a multiple and a non-multiple of $p$.
Considering $p=5$, this rules out all $n$ except possibly $n\equiv 0\pmod 5$.
And considering $p=7$, this rules out all $n$ exept possibly $n\equiv 1\pmod 7$.
Thus we have ruled out all $n$ except possibly $n\equiv 15\pmod{35}$ (Chinese Remainder Theorem), i.e., $n=15, 50, 85, 120, 155, \ldots$.
Of these, $n=15$ is quickly rules out by considering the prime $p=17$, and $p=11$ rules out $n=50,85,120$. We conclude that $n\ge 155$.

On the other hand, $(2)$ is a polynomial in $n$ with integer coefficients and constant term  $\le 120$ in absolute value. It follows that $n\le 120$.

As we cannot have both $n\le 120$ and $n\ge 155$, no solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch: unless $n$ is small, we clearly need $A$ and $B$ to have three elements each. Pick one partition, set the products equal and you get a quadratic equation. There are ten possible partitions, each with its own quadratic equation. Some (like one of the sets containing $n,n+1$ and $n+2$) can be ruled out without checking the quadratic equation. The rest you can solve.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is the special case of the proposition below when $p=7$.

> **Proposition.** Let $p$ be a prime natural number with $p\equiv -1\pmod{4}$, and $n$ an integer.  Then, the set $S:=\{n+1,n+2,n+3,\ldots,n+p-1\}$ cannot be partitioned into two disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ with $$\prod_{a\in A}\,a=\prod_{b\in B}\,b\,.$$

***Proof.*** If $S$ contains an element divisible by $p$, then this element is unique, whence $S$ cannot be partition as $S=A\sqcup B$ with $\prod_{a\in A}\,a=\prod_{b\in B}\,b$.  This is because one product is divisible by $p$ and the other is not.

If $S$ does not contain an element divisible by $p$, then $n\equiv0\pmod{p}$. Ergo,
$$\prod_{s\in S}\,s\equiv1\cdot 2\cdot\ldots\cdot (p-1)=(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod{p}$$
by [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem).  As $-1$ is a quadratic nonresidue modulo $p$, the set $S$ cannot be partitioned into $A\sqcup B$ with $\prod_{a\in A}\,a=\prod_{b\in B}\,b$.

> **Remark.** A more general result is proven by P. Erdös and J. L. Selfridge that the product of consecutive positive integers is never a perfect power of an integer.  See [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256050816).

Answer (score 0):

I realise my answer is very similar to Hagen von Eitzen's, but I think it is a little simpler.

It's already been shown that both sets must have three elements, so I'll use Hagen's notation
$$n(n+a_1)(n+a_2)=(n+a_3)(n+a_4)(n+a_5)$$
where $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5\}=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Modulo $n$, this equation becomes $0=a_3a_4a_5\bmod n$, which means $n|a_3a_4a_5$. Also, $a_3a_4a_5|120$, since $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5=120$, so as a consequence we get $n|120$. However, since $a_3a_4a_5<120$, we also get $n<120$.

The rest of the proof is largely identical to that of Hagen, except that $n|120$, $n<120$, makes elimination of alternatives easier.

If a prime number $p$ divides one of the factors, it must also divide another: one in $A$ and one in $B$.

If $p=7$, it cannot divide more than one factor. Therefore, none of the factors can be divisible by $7$. This is only the case if $n=1\bmod 7$.

If $p=5$, at least one factor must be divisible by 5, but no more than two can be. That means exactly two of the factors are divisible by 5, which is only the case if $n=0\bmod 5$.

These two results make $n=15\bmod 35$ which, together with $n<120$, makes $n\in\{15, 50, 85\}$. Of these, only $n=15$ makes $n|120$.

However, if $n=15$, one of the factors is 17, which makes one side divisible by 17 while the other is not.